# Every time I start the project always just writes that " THIS IS NOT VALID" even if the numbers that I give are right

Tags: c, function, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
bool valid_triangel(double x , double y , double z );

int main(void)
{
    double a = get_double   ("give me first length : ");
    
    double b = get_double  ("give me second length : ");
     
    double c = get_double   ("give me third length : ");
    
    bool valid_triangel(double a , double b , double c );
    
    if ( (bool) valid_triangel ) { printf("THIS IS NOT VALID /n "); }
   
    else { printf("THAT IS A TRIANGEL /n " ); }
    
}

bool valid_triangel(double x , double y , double z )
{
    if ((x + y >= z )  || (x + z >= y) || (z + y >= x ) )  { return false ; }
    
    if ( x <= 0 || y <= 0  || z <= 0 )  { return false ; }
    
    return true ;
    
}
```

The expectation is that if you write numbers that don't give a triangle then it writes " THIS IS NOT VALID " and if the numbers give a triangle then it writes " THAT IS A TRIANGEL "

Comment: You never call the function valid triangle, also you have the forward decleration of the function inside main, do this really compile?

Comment: Concerning: `if ((x + y >= z )  || (x + z >= y) || (z + y >= x ) )  { return false ; }` I believe there is a design flaw in your approach. Isn't it very usual for a triangle that the sum of lengths of two sides is greater than the length of the third?

Comment: `if ( (bool) valid_triangel )` --> `if ( valid_triangel(a, b, c) )`

Comment: `(x + y >= z )`, `(x + z >= y)` and `(z + y >= x )` one of these three expression is going to be `true`. They all cannot be `false` for any combination of values of `x`, `y` and `z`, provided their value is greater than or equal to `0`.

Comment: That hard cast you wedged in to `if ( (bool) valid_triangel )` for no reason other than to squelch a compile-time warning/error should have been reconciliation that (a) something isn't right, and (b) that isn't the way to solve it. Refer to your C++ text on how to *call* a function (which any book should have shown you prior to showing how to *write* one).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You are casting `(bool) valid_triangel` the address of the function instead of calling it.  This will always be non-NULL and the corresponding true branch of the if condition will be executed irregardless of input.
2. (non-issue) I don't have cs50.h installed so I wrote a quick `get_double()` to test your code.
3. Removed the declaration of `valid_tringel()` inside `main()`.
4. Fixed typo (triangle).
5. `(x + y >= z )  || (x + z >= y) || (z + y >= x )` is inverted in `valid_triangle()`.  As you return boolean just express is directly instead of an `if` condition:

> According to the first triangle inequality theorem, the lengths of any two sides of a triangle must add up to more than the length of the third side.[1](https://sciencing.com/rules-length-triangle-sides-8606207.html)

5. Used early return style in `main()` so the normal case is not indented (purely a matter of style).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

double get_double(const char *s) {
    printf("%s", s);
    double d;
    scanf("%lf", &d);
    return d;
}

bool valid_triangle(double x, double y, double z) {
    return
        x > 0 &&
        y > 0 &&
        z > 0 &&
        x + y > z &&
        x + z > y &&
        z + y > x;
}

int main(void) {
    double a = get_double("give me first length : ");
    double b = get_double("give me second length : ");
    double c = get_double("give me third length : ");
    if(!valid_triangle(a, b, c)) {
        printf("THIS IS NOT VALID\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("THAT IS A TRIANGLE\n");
}
```

and here is example output:

```
give me first length : -1
give me second length : 1
give me third length : 10
THIS IS NOT VALID

give me first length : 1
give me second length : 2
give me third length : 3
THIS IS NOT VALID

give me first length : 7
give me second length : 10
give me third length : 5
THAT IS A TRIANGLE
```